# Button click counter [PHP]

Tags: php, html

I tried to create a variable to store a count of button clicked. Unfortunetlly i get this error:

```
 Undefined variable: counter
```

It's my code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $counter = isset($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;
    if(isset($_POST["button"])){
        $counter++;
        echo $counter;
    }
}
```

And it's a form:

```
<form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = post>
    <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "Submit" >
    <input type = "hidden" name = "counter" value = "<?php print $counter; ?>"; />
</form>
```

Anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this code all in the same script?

Comment: The ternary if looks like it should aleviate that error, so cant help with that, **but** as php memory is destroyed every request, **your counter will never work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your code. Its working at my end. You need to check two points:

1. PHP code should be above on HTML, HTML code will come after PHP code. So that `$counter` variable will be initialized.
2. PHP and HTML code should be on same page.

---

**As OP edited the question:** So, the line `$counter = isset($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;` should not be in if-block. To be sure, ** Make this line as a first line of PHP file. Then only `$counter` variable will be available for whole page.

Comment: Are you sure? It's like you say but still doesn't work.

Comment: @KoinArab I am sure, I copied your code and paste in my test.php file and run it... counter is increasing on button click. I didn't changed a bit even.

Comment: @KoinArab  `$counter = isset($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;` **don't put this line in if block, it should be on TOP of PHP file.** make it first line of file.

Comment: Yes, it's works fine now :) Thanks! But can you tell me why this work?

Comment: @KoinArab Because, When you first time open the page then `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` is not set to `"POST"`, as you haven't click on Submit button yet.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you want to save the counter, you can use sessions. Like this:

```
session_start();

// if counter is not set, set to zero
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

// if button is pressed, increment counter
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    ++$_SESSION['counter'];
}    

// reset counter
if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Counter" />
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    <br/><?php echo $_SESSION['counter']; ?>
</form>
```

By the way, your current code will show an `Undefined index error` because you are `echoing` `$counter` on your form but you haven't initialized it yet. It will only exist, upon first form submission, not upon first normal load of the page.

Comment: So is it possible in my current code to show that counter on the web? If no i get your code :)

Comment: @KoinArab of course it's fixable you need to check the one on the form also. [check this live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VIN1gj)

Answer (score 0):

Variable is not defined because of this u get this error.

To hide this error write this in top of page `error_reporting(0)`.

Check [this..how to defined variable?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

you try to use a undelaired variable

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "counter" value = "<?php print $counter; ?>"; />
................................................................^
```

this var doesn't exists as the error says. guess you have a wrong setup of your code.

like the php is not on the same side or not above the html