# Passing a button count back to a function PHP

Tags: php

Sorry gang, I'm a beginner.

I'm trying to learn how to pass the value in a counter from a `index.php` file back into a function.

Essentially, I have two files:

`index.php` and `function.php`

Every time a button is clicked, it pull a random set of information from an array.

I would like to limit what can be pulled (excluding prior items that have been displayed in the array). I have the logic worked out, but not how to pass a counter value back to the function.

In the `index.php` file there is a line:

```
echo "<button id=\"loadQuote\" onclick=\"window.location.reload(true)\" >Show` another item</button>";
```

Each time the `onlick` event is hit, I want to increment a counter. Using something like `counter--`.

Then that counter would get passed back to the function. I'm not directly calling the function, it just in an include.

In the `function.php` I've tried to add logic as below:

```
if (isset($counter) and $counter = 0){        
    $counter = count($myarray);
} elseif (isset($counter)) {
} else {
    $counter = count($myarray);
}
```

But the counter is always equal to `count(myarray)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you need a session variable so the value will persist between calls to the script.

Comment: state is not persistent between calls, so must use something to store value between calls, like session variable, write to file, or write to database. The first is probably most appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

This previous query should help you...

[Button click counter [PHP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306092/button-click-counter-php)

Takeaways: Store the value of 'counter' in a global variable like $_POST so that it can persist across requests.

btw, `=` means 'set', `==` means 'equal to' and `===` means 'identical to'.

Hope this helps.